# While Loop using a counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make it where a user inputs names of guests using the while loop and break function and when the loop ends i want the list to print out in numbered order like

1. james
2. carl
3. lisa
4. bryan

but there is no set limit on how many names can be entered

I have tried already the while true loop but when i use the

```
print("\nMy Wedding Attendees are: "  "\n", extra)
```

it only prints out My wedding Attendees are:
but not the names

```py
print("Now enter the names of other people you are inviting to your wedding\n")
counter = 1
extra = input("Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): ")
while counter >= 1:       #WHILE loop
    extra = input("Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): ")
    counter = counter + 1
    if extra == "":
        break     #break Statement
print("\nMy Wedding Attendees are: "  "\n", extra)
```

I expect it to look like

My wedding attendees are:
1. name
2. name
3. name
4. name

Comment: Please add indentation to your code.

Comment: You don't actually store the `extra` input and so after the loop it will always be the empty string.  Consider storing the responses to be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by using the below code:

```
counter = 1
extra=[' ']  #initializing a random value for extra at the start.
a=[]

while extra != '':     
     extra = input("Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): ")
     a.append(extra)
     counter += 1

print("\nMy Wedding Attendees are: "  "\n")
a.pop(-1) #removing the '' from the list, as we do not need it 

j=1
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    print(str(j)+'. '+a[i])
    j+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically overwrite `extra` in every loop iteration, that is why no names are printed. I suggest you collect all guest names (with assigned counters) in a list and then print it. For example:

```
print("Now enter the names of other people you are inviting to your wedding\n")

counter = 0

guest_names = list()

while True:
    guest_name = input("Guest's name (or press Enter to quit): ")
    if guest_name == "":
        break
    counter += 1
    guest_names.append(str(counter) + ". " + guest_name)  # record all names
print("\nMy wedding attendees are:\n" + " ".join(guest_names))
```

And the output will be (tested in Jupyter notebook):

```
Now enter the names of other people you are inviting to your wedding

Guest's name (or press Enter to quit): John
Guest's name (or press Enter to quit): Marie
Guest's name (or press Enter to quit): Sebbe
Guest's name (or press Enter to quit): David
Guest's name (or press Enter to quit): 

My Wedding Attendees are:
1. John 2. Marie 3. Sebbe 4. David
```

If you want linebreaks between the names, you should use a newline separator with `join()`:

```
print("\nMy wedding attendees are:\n" + "\n".join(guest_names))
```

In this case, the output will be:

```
My wedding attendees are:
1. John
2. Marie
3. Sebbe
4. David
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you are not saving the data anywhere. I have written a code using enumerate which removes the need of count variable in your case. You can read about it in the documentation. The code is

**Code**

```py
print("Now enter the names of other people you are inviting to your wedding\n")

attendes = []  # Keep names of guest

flag = True  # To keep loop control

while flag is True:
    name = input("Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): ")
    if name is not "":  # If not empty then add to list
        attendes.append(name)
    else:  # stop the loop
        flag = False

print("\nMy Wedding Attendees are: "  "\n")

# No need for count when using enumerate
for no, name in enumerate(attendes, 1):
    print('{}. {}'.format(no, name), end=', ')
    # If you don't want the , in output just use end=' '
```

Giving output of

```
Now enter the names of other people you are inviting to your wedding

Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): A
Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): B
Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): C
Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit): D
Guest's Name(or press Enter to quit):

My Wedding Attendees are:

1. A, 2. B, 3. C, 4. D,
```